# Show All Succeeding Inspections After the 1st Inspection or Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day, I have a inspection table and I want to retrieve vehicle's succeeding inspections with the status excluding the Min Inspection date or the first inspection. Basically the result would be the second up to last inspection.

```
InspectionDate  PlateNo     TickeStatus
01-15-12        A            Open
01-23-12        c            Open
01-17-12        A            Close
02-23-12        c            Open
02-15-12        A            Open
03-23-12        c            Open
03-15-12        A            Close
03-28-12        c            Close
04-15-12        A            Open
04-23-12        c            Close
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `row_number()` to assign a sequential number to each inspection for a plate.  Then just select where the row number is greater than 1:

```
select InspectionDate, PlateNo, TicketStatus
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PlateNo order by TickeStatus) as seqnum
      from inspection i
     ) i
where seqnum > 1
```

Comment: @user2388811 . . . Yes, I clarified the query.